# What will happen if I accept an anwer after bounty expired?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer

I have a question with bounty offered.

Till the expiry of bounty, I haven't accepted any answers.

So as per my understanding the bounty will be given to the person with oldest answer and more than 2 up-votes.

What will happen if I accept another answer after the bounty has been rewarded automatically.

Will the bounty taken back from the user who got the bounty?

Will the accepted answer get bounty?

Will both answer get bounty by taking extra rep?

Comment: Simple explanation: bounties are completely unrelated to answer accepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounties, once rewarded, are not changed.

Also, minor correction: the bounty is actually given to the highest-scored post; the age of the posts is a tiebreaker. See: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work?rq=1)